# Why can't I access terminal on vscode dev neither on edge nor chrome?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I can not run any program.

As per the instruction I went to vscode dev.
Open up my repository to run a test program.

However, unfortunately, I can not run any of my programs.
I have checked the doctrine which said that only chrome and edge are supported.

But I can not run my program on the terminal window because it tells the code can only run on environments such as codespaces, and local vs code.
What do I miss so that the problem is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

As [VSCode(.dev) issue 166506](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/166506) illustrates, you cannot access terminal from your browser probably because that menu entry was hidden/removed on purpose.

With VSCode 1.75 (Jan. 2023), it will be restored with an explanation.

> I'm guessing we intentionally suppressed it because terminals can't run in the web, but participants were simply confused that it wasn't there without connecting its absence to the fact that `vscode.dev` was a browser application.
>
> Additionally, RemoteHub contributes a welcome view for the terminal which is one of the primary ways we explain that users must continue working elsewhere to run or debug code, and the fact that the terminal is completely suppressed means one less opportunity for users to organically learn the limitations of `vscode.dev` through our welcome views.
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/30305945/202292244-2a16ca2f-5e09-43f6-9aee-2549eb42c129.png]

The message is the one you saw:

> Terminal are not available in the web editor.
> To use the terminal, you will need to continue in an environment that can run code, like a codespace or local VS Code.

You can develop remotely, but you need to execute locally.